# Right management for a web server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, webserver

I just setup my new server, and there are problems with right management :

My /var/www is owned by root and the group "www-data".

But I would like my user could put his data in his /home/user. And when I do it (and change th VirtualHost), apache said "Permission denied"…

So how to setup correct rights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mod_userdir to enable per-user webdirectories.

There is a good documentation on how to set it up [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will test it (and remove my ugly hack).